Identify the movie about a sexually frustrated criminal
I think it's about a sex maniac. Probably it was part of a TV series. I saw only the beginning of this film on Russian TV in the early 90s, definitely it was a foreign film (I'm almost sure American) and as I remember it looked like late 80s or early 90s film, not older.
A man (who looks like a beer-drinker, I thought that the actor was John Goodman but I looked through his filmography and havn't found a film that fits) calls on radio station and says smth like "I am not so young, girls don't like me any more". The next scene is showing him in a bar meeting a girl, he goes to buy her a drink but when he returns she's with another man, a better looking one.
I changed the channel for some time, then in a few minutes I returned to the movie. The scene was: that girl is in bed with the handsome guy and our hero stands by the bed pointing a pistol at them. Then he tries to give pistol to this man (well to the handsome one which is in bed) and says "C'mon, kill me!" and that guy shivers and doesn't take the pistol. 
That's all, I don't remember anything more.

Why does the behavior described here make him a "sex maniac"?  You might want to expand your description of this behavior as meeting a girl in a bar does not make him a maniac.

@iandotkelly - Maybe it's better to say "sexually frustrated criminal", I cannot be sure now, I saw the movie (partially) a long time ago, but my guess is he went on to be a serial killer

While not a perfect match to your plot description, several things you describe remind me strongly of Sea of Love, starring Al Pacino and John Goodman. Pacino and Goodman are hunting a serial killer who places personal ads in a newspaper. There are several scenes throughout the film taking place in bars, and there is a climactic scene (with Pacino, however, not Goodman) in which a confrontation at gunpoint happens while one is in bed and the other stands over him.

Thank you very much for your answer. No, it's not Sea of Love, I've already seen it, actually found it through imdb: the description (as you mentioned) seemed to fit my 'mystery film'. But now after I've asked this question on a film forum for the second time, I'm not so sure the movie actually exists. Maybe after 20 years my memories got mixed up and these scenes, I remember, are from various films.
